# Xcode7 Beta IOS9 Cannot Create Notifications

Tags: xcode, swift

I semi-recently updated to Xcode 7 and IOS9 but I am encountering an issue. When I try to follow tutorials, I am told to add this line of code:

```
let notificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
```

However, this causes an error that says "Binary operator cannot be applied to two UIUserNotificationType operands." If anyone knows a work-around to this I would very much appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Swift 2, Apple has added `OptionSetType`'s.  Use an array of options values instead of boolean operations like OR.

```
let notificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
```

EDIT:
I think a better way to express this would be the following.

```
let notificationType: UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
```

Comment: Now I am getting an another issue. "Cannot call value of non function type '[UILocalNotification]'" for :UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications(UINotification)